# Retrieve the value of a property in a record, by addressing the property with a variable

Tags: applescript

Say I have a record like this:

```
set my_record to {song1:"Song 1", song2:"Song 2", song3:"Song 3", book1:"Book 1", book2:"Book 2", book3:"Book 3"}
```

By saying..

```
return song2 of my_record
```

.. I can retrieve the value of item1

Now I want to retrieve an item by addressing it with a variable

I tried something like this:

```
set current_song to "song" & 2
return current_song of my_record
```

But this returns an error.

Do I need to convert the string to another type or is what I'm trying not possible?

Comment: I added a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking about, but at least you can do like this, to set a song from your record into a variable. If you want to change the properties, then that can be done with second level evaluation, through a `run script`

```
set  {song2:ThisSong} to  my_record 
— populates ThisSong with the contents of the field song2
```

Second level evaluation (untested) would be something like:

```
run script "set {song" & 2 & ":ThisSong} to my_record"
— uses second level evaluation to construct the field label on the fly.
```

**Edit** Here is a tested example, although I think it should be somewhat easier to perform the second level evaluation, and pass in, and out values of variables, this is the only thing I made to work.

```
 property mrec : {book1:"Tom Sawyer", book2:"Two twins"}
 property thisBook : missing value
 run script "set {book" & 1 & ": my thisBook} to properties of my mrec"
 log thisBook
```

Comment: `set my_books to {book1:"Tom Sawyer", book2:"Two twins"}
display notification (book1 of my_books)`

What the above code does, I would like to apply to multiple record items, like this:

`set my_books to {book1:"Tom Sawyer", book2:"Two twins"}
repeat with a_book from 1 to length of my_books
 display notification ("book" & "a_book" of my_books)
end repeat`

I want to compose the name of the identifier with one literal part ("book"), and one variable part ("a_book"). But I have the impression that it's not possible..

Comment: The only way you can do it, is the way I do it above, with second level evaluation, by constructing a script by concatenating strings, which is then run, and returns the resulting property into a property of the calling script. You should be able to incorporate the snippet I provided you with into a repeat loop, which first extracts the property, then call display notification.

Comment: If you want to use a variable, or variables, to contain the parts that I have used as literals, then you can do so, by containing the literals in properties,  like you would do with normal string concatenation. Then the "script will be  created with the right property first, as the string is concatenated, and then the correct property will be returned into the script-property of your choice  when the script is run (the second level evaluation).